# Dynamically created PictureBox rendering problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

The end goal is a somewhat playable memory game. Currently, I'm stuck on a rendering problem. I have the following classes:

**Field**, which is an abstract `UserControl`:

```
public abstract class Field : UserControl
{
    protected PictureBox _pictureBox;

    public Field()
    {
        _pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        _pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.empty;
        _pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        _pictureBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Controls.Add(_pictureBox);
    }

    // ...
    // some abstract methods, not currently important
}
```

**MemoryField**, which derives from Field:

```
public class MemoryField : Field
{
    public MemoryField(Form parent, int xPos, int yPos, int xSize, int ySize)
    {
        _pictureBox.ClientSize = new Size(xSize, ySize);
        _pictureBox.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
        _pictureBox.Parent = parent;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And finally, **MainForm** which is an entry point for my application:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly int fieldWidth = 100; // 150 no rendering problems at all
    private readonly int fieldHeight = 100;

    public MainForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) // 6 rows
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) // 10 columns
            {
                Field field = new MemoryField(this, 
                    x * (fieldWidth + 3), // xPos, 3 is for a small space between fields
                    labelTimer.Location.Y + labelTimer.Height + y * (fieldHeight + 3), // yPos
                    fieldWidth, 
                    fieldHeight);

                this.Controls.Add(field);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's where my problem lies:
In those `for` loops I'm trying to generate a 6x10 grid of `Field`s (with each containing a `PictureBox` 100x100 px in size). I do that almost successfully, as my second field is not rendered correctly:
[image: Rendering problem with field size of 100x100 px]

Only thing I found that works (fixes the problem completely) is making field bigger (i.e. 150px). On the other hand, making it smaller (i.e. 50px) makes the problem even bigger:

[image: Rendering problem with field size of 50x50 px]

---

**Maybe useful information and things I've tried:**

- My MainForm is `AutoSize = true;` with `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink;`
- My MainForm (initially) doesn't contain any components except `menuStrip` and `label`
- I tried changing `PictureBox.Image` property, that **didn't** work.
- I tried creating the grid with just `PictureBox` controls (not using `Field` as a `PictureBox` wrapper), that **did** work.
- I tried placing `labelTimer` in that "problematic area" which **does** fix the problem depending on where exactly I put it. (because field positioning depends on `labelTimer` 's position and height)
- I tried relaunching visual studio 2017, **didn't** work.

Of course, I could just change the size to 150px and move on, but I'm really curious to see what's the root of this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the link with `labelTimer`, does the problem occur without this `labelTimer` control? If it does, I suggest you remove it from your sample code and snapshots to make it less cluttered! But maybe it does relate.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `_pictureBox.Parent = parent;`? Don't do that. The PictureBox should be handled by the UserControl. Btw, a UserControl already knows its parent, it's `[UC].ParentForm` (inherited from ContainerControl). At least, set `_PictureBox.BringToFront();`. But you shouldn't, really.

Comment: I thought that was Hiragana in the pictureboxes, until I took a closer look :)
this has probably nothing to do with your user control, it is another control obscuring part of stuff rendered with lower z-order. Try creating everything bottom-up, right-to left so as to cover it up, or identify what it is and remove it (`labelTimer`?) apart from that, consider `Field` deriving from `PictureBox` (subclassing it) - one depth less in your control hierarchy.

Comment: IMO unnecessary abstraction here. Place the `Picturebox`es directly inside a `TableLayoutPanel` and be done with it.

Comment: The UserControl's Size property is not set.  It is the only one you can see, the others are too large as well but overlapped by the PictureBox controls.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for the suggestions! The main problem, indeed, was setting size and location for `_pictureBox` and not setting any of those for `Field` (as suggested by @hans-passant and covered in the chosen answer). I have also removed `.Parent = parent` as it is not needed (suggested by @jimi). Now it's left for me to consider `TableLayoutPanel` and/or derive `Field` from `PictureBox ` instead of wrapping it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do to fix the problem is something you've already tried - using directly a `PictureBox` instead of a `Field`. Now, considering that you only use `Field` to wrap a `PictureBox`, you could inherit from `PictureBox` instead of just wrapping it.
Changing your classes to these will fix the issue as you've noticed:

```cs
public abstract class Field : PictureBox {

    public Field() {
        Image = Image.FromFile(@"Bomb01.jpg");
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        Size = new Size(100, 100);
    }

    // ...
    // some abstract methods, not currently important
}

public class MemoryField : Field {
    public MemoryField(Form parent, int xPos, int yPos, int xSize, int ySize) {
        ClientSize = new Size(xSize, ySize);
        Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The real reason it was not working has to do with both *sizing* and *positioning* of each `Field` and their subcomponents. You should not set the `Location` of each `_pictureBox` relatively to its parent `MemoryField`, but rather change the `Location` of the `MemoryField` relatively to its parent `Form`.

You should also set the size of your `MemoryField` to the size of its child `_pictureBox` otherwise it won't size correctly to fit its content.

```cs
public class MemoryField : Field {
    public MemoryField(Form parent, int xSize, int ySize) {
        _pictureBox.ClientSize = new Size(xSize, ySize);
        // I removed the setting of Location for the _pictureBox.
        this.Size = _pictureBox.ClientSize; // size container to its wrapped PictureBox
        this.Parent = parent; // not needed
    }
    // ...
}
```

and change your creation inner loop to

```cs
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) // 10 columns
{
    Field field = new MemoryField(this,
        fieldWidth,
        fieldHeight);
    field.Location = new Point(x * (fieldWidth + 3), 0 + 0 + y * (fieldHeight + 3)); // Set the Location here instead!
    this.Controls.Add(field);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Fixes my situation, suggests a better overall solution and explains everything I didn't quite understand previously. Thank you!